# What plural-only nouns does English have?

Tags: plural-forms, singular-vs-plural

Some nouns, [like "clothes,"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/60849/20777) exist in the plural only.
Is there a list of such nouns, or a rule or pattern that describes the set, and can be used to figure out if a singular form of a plural noun does or does not exist?

Comment: ***12 nouns that are always plurals*** : http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/05/12-nouns-that-are-always-plurals/ - ***Nouns That Can Only Be Plural***  - http://www.jincywillett.com/journal/2009/12/08/nouns-that-can-only-be-plural/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 5):

They're called [pluralia tantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum) (Latin for "plural only", singular form: plurale tantum), defined by Wikipedia there as...

> *a noun that appears only in the plural form and does not have a singular variant for referring to a single object. In a less strict usage of the term, it can also refer to nouns whose singular form is rarely used.*

There's a list of a dozen examples at [oxforddictionaries](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/05/12-nouns-that-are-always-plurals/) *(trousers, scissors, glasses, clothes, marginalia, folk, shenanigans, loggerheads, cahoots, amends, smithereens, thanks)* from which it should be obvious that some are only *pluralia tantum* in specific contexts with specific meanings.

I don't think there's any "rule" that would help you identify which words work like this (or in which *contexts*). You just have to remember it as and when you learn each relevant word and meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Is it ironic that the term has a singular form, and/or that it's in Latin?

Comment: @WBT: Well, when I first wrote that Wikipedia link my context required a plural, and I wasn't planning to mention the singular. But when I actually went to the site myself and saw that they'd given both forms, I couldn't resist alluding to the ***non-** self-referential* nature of the term. Looking at Oxford's list again, I think there's definitely a tendency for dialectal/slang usages to be of this type. I've just thought of *It gives me the **willies / heebie-jeebies / screaming abdabs / creeps***, for example, and I'm sure there are many more like that.