# Non-countable nouns in English that end on "-s"

Tags: nouns, plural-forms, uncountable-nouns

The word "news" appears to be plural - [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/news) says its origin is "*Late Middle English plural of new, translating Old French noveles or medieval Latin nova ‘new things’.*" Yet in modern English "news" is a [mass noun](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mass_noun), which means it is non-countable.

How is a plural noun non-countable?

Besides "news", what are some other non-countable nouns in English that end on "-s"?

Comment: As a reminder, Stack Exchange questions should be about real-life problems, not curiosities or trivia. Additionally, you are expected to demonstrate your initial attempts at research.

Comment: Sorry, I feel I acted too hastily in closing. I reopened with the hopes that someone could provide an abstraction for this (or possibly a duplicate, not so much a list), like the answer here: [What plural-only nouns does English have?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104530/what-plural-only-nouns-does-english-have). Of course, users are still welcome to vote to close if they feel differently.

Comment: At first glance, this question *does* seem awfully broad.  I think it could be usefully answered with a list of *categories* of lexical items which fit the OP's criteria, though, giving examples in each category, so I think we can leave the question open.

Comment: @snailcar As worded, the question asks for an open-ended list of answers, all of which are equally valid. Honestly, I don't know how the phrase "what are some" hasn't been banned yet across SE.

Comment: Has the OP done  research before  asking this  question? why are some questions  particularly  targetted?

Comment: I think sometimes  the users and  moderators are too liberal and sometimes too rigid.I do not know how  this question is allowed  without putting onhold.

Comment: @JVL It's very much up to the community to decide.  If you think it should be closed, please feel free to flag the question and pick the close reason you think fits best (for example, Too Broad).

Comment: I personally felt it was a valid question. Try to think *why* a non-native English speaker might ask this. My assumption is that "news" sounds like a plural (the origin of the word *is* a plural of 'new', or 'novelties' - new things) which is a seeming conflict with it being a mass-noun.

Comment: @Astralbee - You are right. This was my reason and the only reason why I asked this question.

Comment: @brilliant Hope you don't mind but I have edited your question to include these details which I assumed you meant and you have confirmed were the reason for your question.

Comment: @Astralbee - Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Gas
- Stress
- Happiness
- Glass
- Genetics

I'm sure there are lots more, this isn't an exhaustive list.

You might be under the impression that "news" is unique because it *sounds like a plural* (and the etymology of the word *is* a plural of "new", or "new things"). I can see how that might seem to conflict with it being a mass noun.

Firstly, the origins, or etymology of a word, are often irrelevant to its modern-day use. In the case of "news", it is considered a mass-noun and not a plural. Although we have the word "new" in English, it is used as an adjective. Rather than being related, they are different words that have a common origin.

Also, not every word ending in 's' is a plural (as seen from my examples). Your best bet for finding more examples is to consider *abstract concepts* such as my example 'happiness' or *materials* like 'glass' and 'gas'.

Answer (score 1):

What about diseases?

**Mumps,measles**

Physics, statistics,politics etc